# Why does SOQL show there is data but SOSL returns no results?

Tags: soql, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I want to search for a list of phrases. I used SOSL to search for a string to begin with but it is returning zero results yet when I run a soql I can see there is data. Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
FIND {Animal} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Engagements__c(Name)
```

[image]

The SOQL results..

```
select name, Other_Issue_Area__c, Primary_Issue_Area__c from Engagements__c
```

[image: soql]

Comment: What is the Data Type of `Other_Issue_Area__c` & `Primary_Issue_Area__c` on Case?

Comment: That and could it be a permission issue?

Comment: They are picklist fields. Let me check the permissions. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I have both read and edit access on the two fields.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like picklist fields are not searchable currently.

It is listed on the ideas [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrnQAAS)